# Unity for every 25 numbers

Tags: c#, loops, if-statement, unity-game-engine

So i had this:

```
if (bought.count == bought.needForUpgrade)
        {
            bought.timeToComplete /= 2;
            bought.needForUpgrade += 25;
        }
```

It was good, but i made a buy function so you can buy items by 1,10,25 And i want to reduce the `bought.timeToComeplete by 2` for every 25 number its count passes, so for example i have 1 from that item, then i decide to buy 25, then i'll have 26. I could do it with a lot of `if statements` but i dont want to write it all day that `if(bought.count >= 25 && bought.count <= 50)` .. etc

Comment: Can you clarify the question?  Are you just asking about how to determine how many times 25 goes into bought.needForUpgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add an additional value that saves how often you already upgraded and checks if you got the next "level".
For this solution I assume `bought.count` and `bought.needForUpgrade` are of type integer:

```
int boughtLevel = 0;

if (bought.count / bought.needForUpgrade > boughtLevel)
{
    // Do your stuff here
    boughtLevel = bought.count / bought.needForUpgrade;
}
```

Else you would have to cast them before dividing:

```
int boughtLevel = 0;

if ((int)(bought.count / bought.needForUpgrade) > boughtLevel)
{
    // Do your stuff here
    boughtLevel = (int)(bought.count / bought.needForUpgrade); // Not necessary because boughtLevel is of type integer
}
```